# Android: Thread infinite loop / phone overheating

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, android-activity, communication

I'm working on a Thread that handles all server connections:

```
public void run() {
    //this initializes Socket and PrintWriter/DataInputStream
    connect(server, port); 

    while(true) {
         //queue is a BlockingQueue where I put the messages to send
         while(!queue.isEmpty()) s
            //COMMUNICATE-WITH-SERVER-CODE
           }
    }   
}
```

The code works, but after a minute or so, my phone starts overheating and battery goes down fast. I know it's because of the infinite loop.

How can I solve it? I want a `Thread` which, once started, keeps the connection to the server (so that `DataInputStream` and `PrintWriter` won't be initialized every time). And I want the thread to be responsive: when I click a `Button` it should sent instantaneously a message to the server for processing.

I have implemented a `Handler` for communicating `Thread->Activity`. But how can I communicate `Activity->Thread`?

Any tip would be welcome.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(100)` should help.

Comment: Using a queue tye that actually 'blocks' would be better than introducing an average 50ms latency into an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the solution would be to add a polling intervall, ex: sleep the thread for 500ms after each iteration. But in this case there is no need for that, because we do not have to poll a `BlockingQueue`. From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

> A `Queue` that additionally supports operations that wait for the queue to become non-empty when retrieving an element, and wait for space to become available in the queue when storing an element.

If we use a `BlockingQueue`, then the queue.pop() call blocks if the queue is empty and remains blocked until an entry is pushed onto the queue. There fore there is no need for looping.

However, we will need to have some sort of mechanism to keep the thread from terminating. Here is a simple example:

```
public void run() {
    try {
    while (true) {
        handleServerIO(queue.take());
        }
    }catch (InterruptedException ex) {          
     ... handle ...
    }
}
```

Comment: was about to say the same thing. If you keep it running all the time , it will become unresponsive because you are keeping the CPU busy all the time, and will eventually get ANP message.

Comment: Damn great. I didnt take into account!

Comment: Poster says the queue is 'BockingQueue', which I assume means 'blocking'??  Sleep() calls in polling loops are just lame.

Comment: Automatic 250ms average latency introduced.

Comment: @MartinJames the `while(true)` loop is always active if I don't call `sleep()`. No matter if there is a `BlockingQueue`

Comment: @Thorba - then you are pushing stuff onto the queue faster than it can be popped off and so you will run out of memory.

Comment: @MartinJames what if the queue is mostly empty? I agree `sleep()` is not an optimal solution and it does induce latenzy, but in most apps this will not matter and usually the simplest solution is the best to start with. I will expand this answer when i find some time.

Comment: @MartinJames Not at all. The `sleep` just after `while(true)` puts a delay between every `while(!queue.isEmpty())` comprobation. This way, if I put 100 messages into the queue, the queue will be checked every 500ms, and once it detects that it has messages to attend, inner-loop `while(!queue.isEmpty())` will process them with no delay. On the other hand, if I don't put the `sleep`, it will be checking the inner-while condition as faster as CPU can.

Comment: @Thorba - then its not a blocking queue, which your original post suggested it was in the comments. If it was a blocking queue, 'queue.isEmpty()' should have reduced your CPU use to zero while the queue is empty.

Comment: Is it a blocking queue type that you are simply misusing?

Comment: You realise that a blocking queue does not need any polling loop at all?

Comment: @john - the simplest solution is to use an actual blocking queue correctly.  Polling with Sleep() will work badly, but it will work, and I can almost guarantee that such a bodge will make it into production and result in a poor quality app being delivered.

Comment: @MartinJames my misstake: I did not realise how a `BlockingQueue` works in that context - now i read the docs. The `while(true)` got me off balance.

Comment: @MartinJames I dont realise that tbh. If I erase `while(true)` and queue is empty, the `while(queue.isEmpty())` will be jumped and `run()` method of the Thread will finish. And that's exactly what I don't want. If I'm not correct, could you give a further explanation? Thanks.

Comment: @MartinJames oh wait, u wrote `while(queue.isEmpty())`. So should I use two whiles: one isEmpty and another one !isEmpty, instead of a Sleep and a !isEmpty? Now I see it! Okay :D

Comment: What usually happens is that the queue.pop() call blocks if the queue is empty and remains blocked until an entry is pushed onto the queue.  There is no need to check the queue count, 'isEmpty' or anything like that.   So, while the queue is empty, no CPU is used.

Comment: You still need the while(true) to keep the thread from terminating, but just perform a blocking pop at the top to get the objects whenever they are pushed on.